# How to create two different legend for two different graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm plotting two graphs in a page using `subplot`. The result makes the two graphs have a combined legend. The question is how to make it in to two separate legends and how to merge all fields into one type in legend instead of listing all in legend. (short explanation : To make a legend that define type of graph instead of attribute)

This is my code :

```
pivot = aggregate(x[,8:28], by=list(Field=x$Field), FUN=sum)
          df = melt(data=pivot)

pivot1 = aggregate(df_sales[,8:28], by=list(Excel=df_sales$Excel), FUN=sum)
          df1 = melt(data=pivot1)

a <- ggplotly(ggplot(data=df) + geom_area(aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=Field, group=Field)) +
            labs(title="CO2",xlab="Years",ylab="Values"))
          #ggplotly(b)

b <- ggplotly(ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=Excel)) + geom_area(aes( fill="Field name")) + geom_line(aes( fill="Sales"))+labs(title="CO2",xlab="Years",ylab="Values"))

subplot(a,b)
```

And The result is here:
[image: here]

and I want it to be simply like this :

[image: click here]